# How to store application level variable value in angular 4 and avaialble in all component

Tags: angular, variables

I get JWT token from login api. After that in want to store it to somewhere to available in every component and service and also available from Interceptor to attach it to each http request with Authentication Header.

In service, app level const, static variable, and Injector value are gone after hard refresh.

Currently I am using localstorage but I want some other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use local storage variable, then access it from every component.